# ROWCOUNT é confiável para checagem de alteração?

Tags: sql-server, desempenho, sql-update, arquitetura-de-software

Estou montando uma query para ser executada via DAPPER/C#, minha ideia é não precisa verificar se o dado existe na tabela retornando o objeto para a aplicação, e sim, verificar direto no banco de dado de uma unica vez.

Sei que é possível usar o [MARGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), mas com ele tenho a complicação de não poder usar o  *`WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT`*.

Por isso montei minha query usando o `ROWCOUNT` que devolve a quantidade de linha afetadas e caso seja igual a zero faço o insert.

Minha duvida é se é confiável usar o `ROWCOUNT` para uma situação como essa, sendo que minha tabela pode ter trigger e fazendo outras regras de negocio inclusive update e insert em outras tabelas.

```
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT( 0x4143544956452D53..)
UPDATE MINHA_TABELA
SET CAMPO2 = 44
   ,CAMPO1 = 1
WHERE ID = 1
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT( 0x4143544956452D53..)
    INSERT INTO MINHA_TABELA (ID, CAMPO1, CAMPO2)
    VALUES (1, 1, 44)
END
```

Comment: É sim...........

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, mesmo que a tabela tenha trigger, sabe se ele devolve as linhas afetadas de uma trigger ou só da tabela mesmo?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você executa via dapper se sim dá agora trigger não tenho como verificar e isso não consta na sua pergunta

Comment: Sim , acabei não mencionando a parte da trigger até por acha que era um pouco obvio que uma tabela o tenha. mas vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: segundo a documentação oficial https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 *"Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement"* ou seja, do ultimo comando, então um update e em seguida pegar o valor de rowcount vai retornar os registros alterados nesse comando, agora se uma trigger fizer alterações, já é outro comando

Comment: Não é nem um pouco óbvio que uma tabela qualquer tenha triggers.

Comment: @bfavaretto pra mim é,  mas alterei a pergunta.